# Is there a way to add extra columns to a jstree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using jQuery and jstree. I would like to have extra columns appear to the right of the node labels so that I can put additional info in them such as dates, text, etc.

How can I do this in jstree?

---

This is an example of the layout that I'd like to achieve, but with jstree.

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes its possible, need to know where you want put these extra columns and some more information.

Answer (score 11):

[jsTreeGrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid)

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to do it:

Either **edit the Dom** after jstree has loaded

or

**Edit jstree javascript** file to achieve the desired effect. Start by looking at line 313:

```
this.get_container().html("<ul>...
```